# Blank login/SSO window with Cisco AnyConnect VPN on Ubuntu 22.04.03

Tags: nvidia, permissions, 22.04, vpn, cisco

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 4.10.07061 installed on Ubuntu 22.04.03 was working fine with an internal VPN server that relies on Office365 authentication until recently. Seemingly without warning, the authentication window that pops up after entering the VPN server address is blank.

`cat /var/sys/syslog` returns:

```
Oct 16 16:38:29 UbuL4479 acvpnui[10035]: Message type prompt sent to the user: Please complete the authentication process in the AnyConnect Login window.
...
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 acvpnui[10035]: Function: launchBrowser File: ../../../vpn/WebHelper/Plugin/WebHelperPluginImpl.cpp Line: 783 Browser process launched successfully [pid 10068]
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1000x600: Permission denied
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1000x600: Permission denied
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1000x600: Permission denied
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.desktop[10112]: Failed to create EGL images for DMABufs with file descriptors -1, -1 and -1
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 rtkit-daemon[2254]: Supervising 12 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 rtkit-daemon[2254]: Successfully made thread 10129 of process 10112 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 rtkit-daemon[2254]: Supervising 13 threads of 7 processes of 1 users.
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 rtkit-daemon[2254]: Supervising 13 threads of 7 processes of 1 users.
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 rtkit-daemon[2254]: Successfully made thread 10169 of process 10112 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct 16 16:38:30 UbuL4479 rtkit-daemon[2254]: Supervising 14 threads of 7 processes of 1 users.
Oct 16 16:38:31 UbuL4479 kernel: [  586.958683] audit: type=1107 audit(1697495911.042:149): pid=1391 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.13" mask="receive" pid=7633 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1449 peer_label="unconfined"
Oct 16 16:38:31 UbuL4479 kernel: [  586.958683]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Oct 16 16:38:31 UbuL4479 WebKitNetworkPr[10109]: gssapi step failed: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible: SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate
Oct 16 16:38:36 UbuL4479 kernel: [  591.976441] audit: type=1107 audit(1697495916.062:150): pid=1391 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.13" mask="receive" pid=7633 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1449 peer_label="unconfined"
Oct 16 16:38:36 UbuL4479 kernel: [  591.976441]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting from [Cisco website](https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/anyconnect-4-10-05111-displays-blank-page-instead-of-sso-login/td-p/4648440) for visibility:

Calling the following solves the problem:

```
$ export WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1 
$ /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui
```

The OP at that link reported slow behavior and having to re-login 3-4 times before success, but for me it worked the first time. OP also reports that "it appears to be a webkit bug on NVIDIA graphics '[GTK] Rendering broken with 2.42 on NVIDIA graphics' and affects any other app. that uses webkit".

A temporary fix is to add `export WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1` to `~/.profile` to run at login.